# Extract specific frames of youtube video without downloading video

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture, youtube-dl

I need to extract **specific frames** of an online video to work on an algorithm but I don't want to download the whole video because that would make it highly inefficient.

For starters, I tried working with youtube videos. I can download whole of the video using `youtube-dl` in this way:

```
ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': r'OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_HERE',}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
```

And then I can capture individual frames.

I need to avoid downloading the whole video. After some research, I have found that `ffmpeg` might help me do this. I found no way to download just the frames so if this is not possible, the second option is that I can download specific portions of the video. One such example in linux is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230481/how-to-download-portion-of-video-with-youtube-dl-command/392350#392350) but I couldn't find any solution for python.

What is a good way to download just the frames, or portions of videos (in python) without downloading the entire thing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876292/opencv-capture-online-video-for-further-processing-without-downloading-the-file. Does this helps?

Comment: @AyeshaKhan This answer is downloading all the frames. So what I did was I skipped downloading some of them (say I  downloaded every 300th frame in video, i.e. I downloaded a frame after every 10 secs for a 30 fps video). This seems to work. Although, I am not sure if I am just skipping saving them locally or actually skipping capturing them. Thank you though!

Comment: I have built an API to get frames for youtube videos: https://rapidapi.com/abyesilyurt/api/youtube-screenshot1/details. It requires an http request and returns the image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to add on to the current answer, performance can further be enhanced using multiprocessing. For example, if you wanted to split up the video into frames and process them independently in *num_cpu* processes:

```
import os
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

import cv2
import youtube_dl

def process_video_parallel(url, skip_frames, process_number):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    num_processes = os.cpu_count()
    frames_per_process = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) // num_processes
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frames_per_process * process_number)
    x = 0
    count = 0
    while x < 10 and count < frames_per_process:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        filename =r"PATH\shot"+str(x)+".png"
        x += 1
        cv2.imwrite(filename.format(count), frame)
        count += skip_frames  # Skip 300 frames i.e. 10 seconds for 30 fps
        cap.set(1, count)
    cap.release()



video_url = "..."  # The Youtube URL
ydl_opts = {}
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
info_dict = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)

formats = info_dict.get('formats', None)

print("Obtaining frames")
for f in formats:
    if f.get('format_note', None) == '144p':
        url = f.get('url', None)
        cpu_count = os.cpu_count()
        with Pool(cpu_count) as pool:
            pool.map(partial(process_video_parallel, url, 300), range(cpu_count))
```

For the purposes of this application, since images are just being saved from the video, this may not result in a huge improvement (maybe a few seconds), but if additional algorithms needed to be applied on the frames, it could be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what *@AyeshaKhan* shared in the comments.

After importing `cv2`,`numpy`,`youtube-dl`:

```
    url=saved_url #The Youtube URL
    ydl_opts={}
    ydl=youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
    info_dict=ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)

    formats = info_dict.get('formats',None)
    print("Obtaining frames")
    for f in formats:
        if f.get('format_note',None) == '144p':
            url = f.get('url',None)
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
            x=0
            count=0
            while x<10:
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if not ret:
                    break
                filename =r"PATH\shot"+str(x)+".png"
                x+=1
                cv2.imwrite(filename.format(count), frame)
                count+=300 #Skip 300 frames i.e. 10 seconds for 30 fps
                cap.set(1,count)
                if cv2.waitKey(30)&0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
            cap.release()
```

The answer in the comments was downloading all of the frames so the `count` I added in `.format()` ensured that I skipped the frames as per my requirement.

Additionally, `x` here limits the number to 10.

Although, I am still not sure whether this method is actually capturing the specified frames, or if it is capturing all the frames and just saving the specified frames to my local storage. I needed the former thing.

But this is still fast enough and works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @danielcahall,

This method uses [Ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-overview/index.html) for parallelization instead of `Pool`

**Note: For the first time, it might take more time for initializing the ray components, After the first run, this will be fine**

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import os, ray, shutil
import cv2
import youtube_dl

try:
    os.makedirs('test_fol')
except:
    shutil.rmtree('test_fol')
    os.makedirs('test_fol')

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def process_video_parallel(url, total_frames, process_number):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    num_processes = os.cpu_count()
    frames_per_process = int(total_frames) // num_processes
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frames_per_process * process_number)
    count = frames_per_process * process_number
    
    while count < frames_per_process * (process_number+1):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        filename = f"test_fol/{count}.jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
        count += 1
    cap.release()


t1 = timer()
video_url = "..."  # The Youtube URL
ydl_opts = {}
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
info_dict = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)
duration = info_dict['duration']
formats = info_dict.get('formats', None)

for f in formats:
    if f.get('format_note', None) == '144p':
        url = f.get('url', None)
        cpu_count = os.cpu_count()
        data = ray.get([process_video_parallel.remote(url, int(duration*31), x) for x in range(cpu_count)])
        break
            
print("Total Time", timer()-t1)
```